# Custom Series Label in Chart WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

We have a charting control that display side by side bar chart. It is based on ArguementDataMember "x" and ValueDataMember "y". The Chart is bound with Datasource (chartData, observablecollection) that has properties x,y,z.
Am trying to display "z" in series label. But not able to. getting error

```
"BindingExpression path error: 'z' property not found on 'object' ''SeriesLabelItem' (HashCode=58379838)'. BindingExpression:Path=z; DataItem='SeriesLabelItem' (HashCode=58379838); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"
```

My code is like below

```
 <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D DisplayName="Last Year" Brush="Goldenrod" ArgumentScaleType="Qualitative" ArgumentDataMember="x"  
                                                   ValueDataMember="y" ToolTipEnabled="False"  Name="Last" DataSource="{Binding ChartData}">

                            <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Label >
                                <dxc:SeriesLabel Visible="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Name="lblLast" DataContext="{Binding ChartData}">
                                    <dxc:SeriesLabel.ElementTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding z}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Background="White">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </dxc:SeriesLabel.ElementTemplate>
                                </dxc:SeriesLabel>

                            </dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Label>
                            <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Model>
                                <dxc:SimpleBar2DModel/>
                            </dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Model>
                        </dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D>
```

Answer (score 0):

Element template know nothing about data context of element to which you want to apply template. Inside template you can only bind to properties of SeriesLabelItem. To provide custom text to label you can use CustomDrawSeriesPoint event. Implementation of method would look like this:

```
private void chartControl_CustomDrawSeriesPoint(object sender, CustomDrawSeriesPointEventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass point = e.SeriesPoint.Tag as MyClass;
            if (point != null)
            {
                e.LabelText = point.z;
            }
        }
```

Template will look like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Background="White">
     </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```